# PHPStorm 8 built-in default port disabling

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phpstorm

Each my project is run on a localhost with default PHPStorm port `:63342` and it causes many problems like PageNotFound(404) error.

Is there any way to disable this port or just correct it to act like `localhost/`
Do I need to create a special .htaccess or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest installing MAMP (or similar) to manage your localhost. You can then create a local server configuration within PHPStorm to override the built in server.

More information about creating a local server config here https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-a-local-server-configuration.html

The settings can be found here, in the settings panel (note this is PHPStorm 9, but the location is the same.

[image]

Comment: I use WAMP Server. How can I override built-in server configuration?

Comment: after applying those settings, phpStorm still uses the /localhost:63342/, any suggestions why? I am using XAMP